# A variant of Cauchy-type functional equation conjecture

Tags: cv.complex-variables, gm.general-mathematics, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a complex function such that
$$|f(x-y)|=|f(x)-f(y)|,\qquad x,y\in\mathbb{C}.$$
Is it true that $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),\qquad x,y\in\mathbb{C}?$$

The answer is affirmative when $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a real function, and the proof is not difficult. The above generalization seems harder: I inferred it from a conjecture that I saw in a paper.

Comment: What about $f(x)=x+a$? In any case your question is not appropriate for this site, please use MathStackExchange.

Comment: @abx,if $f(x)=x+a$ not such condition,and this problem I think it's a research question. It's not simple.

Comment: your first equation has unbalanced $|$ (there are three $|$ on the right-hand-side, which makes no sense); in any case, the second equation implies a linear function $f(x)=cx$ and if the first equation is $|f(x-y)|=|f(x)-f(y)|$ that is satisfied for any complex $c$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Actually, there are many (non-continuous) functions besides $f(x)=cx$ that satisfy the second equation (hence also the first equation).

Comment: I voted to close, but after the edit it seems like a reasonable question (with the $\|$ corrected to $|$).

Comment: I voted to reopen per Nik Weaver's comment. @inequality If you can, please edit in a citation to the paper you are referring to.

Comment: I edited the question greatly (for clarity and language), and I voted to reopen it. At the same time, I ask the OP to make a bigger effort (e.g. next time) to formulate his/her question nicely. In particular, the post refers to some paper, hence a reference would be necessary. This site is for professionals, so participants should act like professionals.

Comment: Now it is said there is a  counterexamples

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP should provide a reference to the paper which they mention in the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

counterexample
$$f(x)=1-e^{\Re(x) i}$$